# CCTableView with cocos2d 3.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm trying to get CCTableView working with cocos2d 3.0 but I really don't know where to start. Does anyone have a good tutorial or anything for 3.0? I see there are a few for older versions of cocos2d but nothing for 3.0. Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tutorial are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a short sample. I do recommend just trying out writing some code on your own and then posting what problems you are having with it. It definitely makes for easier answering of questions. You can also create your own subclass of `CCTableViewCell` if you want.

The Header file, SampleTableView.h

```
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "cocos2d-ui.h"

@interface SampleTableView : CCNode <CCTableViewDataSource>
@end
```

The source file: SampleTableView.m

```
float const kNumberOfRows = 30.0f;

@implementation SampleTableView

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        CCTableView* table = [CCTableView node];
        table.dataSource = self; // make our class the data source
        table.block = ^(CCTableView* table) {
            NSLog(@"Cell %d was pressed", (int) table.selectedRow);
        };
        [self addChild:table];
    }
    return self;
}

- (CCTableViewCell*) tableView:(CCTableView*)tableView nodeForRowAtIndex:(NSUInteger) index {
    CCTableViewCell* cell = [CCTableViewCell node];
    cell.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypeMake(CCSizeUnitNormalized, CCSizeUnitUIPoints);
    cell.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1.0f, 32.0f);
    float colorFactor = (index / kNumberOfRows);
    // Just a sample node that changes color with each index value
    CCNodeColor* colorNode = [CCNodeColor nodeWithColor:[CCColor colorWithRed:colorFactor green:(1.0f - colorFactor) blue:(0.2f + 0.5 * colorFactor) ] width:100.0f height:18.0f];
    [cell addChild:colorNode];
    return cell;
}

- (NSUInteger) tableViewNumberOfRows:(CCTableView*) tableView {
    return kNumberOfRows; // just a demo
}
```

And how to add it in your hello world scene or elsewhere:

```
SampleTableView* table = [SampleTableView node];
table.contentSizeType = CCSizeTypeNormalized;
table.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0);
```

Here is a sample screenshot of what it looks like:
[image: SampleScreenshot]

Comment: Can you include in your code how we can detect if a cell got taped?

Comment: @João Abrantes so far I haven't found a way myself despite of the cell having a button.  It seems the scrollview swallows the event

Comment: @JoãoAbrantes I updated the sample to include the block for when a cell is pressed. You also need to make sure the TableViewCell has the correct dimensions.

Comment: @AlexanderN make sure you have the correct size for the Cell, otherwise it might not register the touch.

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the cocos2d-tests-ios.xcodeproj in the cocos2d source.
It has a sample for pretty much every thing implemented in cocos2d, Including a CCTableView sample.

https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone

1. **git clone** cocos2d source.
2. Open the **cocos2d-tests-ios.xcodeproj** project and build/run the **cocos2d-tests-ios** target.

Comment: Tooke a while to find the actual file you was referring to... If anybody needs help it's here https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone/blob/v3.1/cocos2d-ui-tests/tests/CCTableViewTest.m